# Failed to upgrade Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I tried to follow the officiall upgrade documentation, but after I changed every related lines in gradle files I got this error:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics']
>   Could not set unknown property 'obfuscatorVersion' for object of type com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsExtension.

These are the Firebase versions:

firebaseCrashlytics = '17.0.1'

firebaseAnalytics = '17.4.3'

Other related dependencies:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'

If I comment out this line:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

everything is working fine...
I can't upgrade to gradle 4.0.0 because DexGuard doesn't support it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
If anybody using DexGuard them must the Crashlytics plugin should be applied before the DexGuard plugin. 
This piece of magic linked in the release notes...

Comment: confirm it works. Can you attach a link to release notes?

Comment: I don't know where is the public release notes, but if you have an active license, you can find it at the docs/gradle/dexguard-plugin.html#firebaseCrashlytics path.

Comment: I just found it. Thank you. What an awesome dexguard

Answer (score 3):

Use below configuration if your facing build issues using Android studio 4.1

- Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.0
- Gradle Version 6.5

````
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'```
````

Answer (score 1):

Looks like gradle version issue.

Use updated gradle version:-
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"(latest)

or
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'(old)

and updated gradle-wrapper.properties:-
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip(latest)

or
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip(old)

Comment: I updated every dependency to the latest, but it's not solved my problem

Comment: // Remove Fabric's Maven repository.
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

// Add Google's Maven repository (if it's not there already).
   google()

Answer (score -2):

**FLUTTER DEVELOPMENT**:

Just for problem in future with **FLUTTER** **framwork** i had the same issue listed here on the question and the problem was in the file **build.gradle** and it gives me the following issue :

Build file 'C:\Users\MyUserName\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterX UI\android\app\build.gradle' line: 23

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'.
> Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project.

AND i am using in pubspec.yaml those plugins :
**firebase_crashlytics**, **firebase_core**.

So what ***caused a porblem*** for me the was in the file **build.gradle** and specificly in those line :

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**

i just ***rearranged*** them as following and it worked like a charm :

**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I hope it will help someone in the future.